# A program with #include<iostream.h>, allows the use of string functions like strlen(). Why?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
{
   char name[] = "Mary Mon";
   cout<<strlen(name);
   return 0;
}
```

This program compiles normally without `#include<string.h>`. Why?

Comment: There is no `<iostream.h>`. I recommend you get a compiler from this millenium.

Comment: <iostream.h> very very old compiler

Comment: Any C++ header can include any other header, so you *might* get some you haven't explicitly asked for. You should include the ones your program needs.

Comment: Have you tried using `iostream` (no `.h`)? If yes, is it behaving the same as before? I hope it's available in your compiler.

Comment: iostream include a lot of header, one of which might be the header that includes strlen function

Comment: Many more things are not guaranteed to work than are guaranteed not to work. You lucked out.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, as pointed out in the comments, there is no standard header file named `<iostream.h>`.  `iostream.h` was a header file used before the C++ language was standardized in 1998.  When the standard was published, the name was changed to just `<iostream>` (without the `.h`).

Secondly, the standard allows headers to include other headers (C++03 §17.4.4.1/1).  So it might happen that your `<iostream.h>` header includes `<string.h>`, probably because some of the template code there relies on some string function.  As a result, your code compiles cleanly.

Nevertheless, you should not rely on this behavior.  In order for your code to be most portable, you should `#include` every header file you need, whether or not they are `#include`d recursively by some other header file.